# best way to work with android gps

Tags: android, gps

So, I want to work with GPS and wanted to know what will be the best approach to achieve my requirement.

Here is what I want :

There are certain predefined locations with its latitude and longitude. Now, I want an alarm to ring when user is within 10m radius of that location. (I know how to setup alarms using pending intent.) I just want to know what will be the best approach to do this.

Currently I have used

```
locationmanager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, intentcode, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You aren't exactly asking a question.  Yes, that will work.  What do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know what will be the best approach... the other one is using locationlistener... I am not sure If i can achieve what I want with onLocationChanged with location listener... or using addProximityAlert is the best one?

Comment: You can do it either way.  onLocationChanged will make you write more code on your own.  The tradeoff is I've heard reports of proximity alerts taking up too much battery on some devices.  There's also the geofencing feature of Google Play Services, but not all devices have that installed (if the OEM doesn't pay Google for it then you have to pirate it to get it).